# How to load all related node without includeing them in cypher in noe4jclinet

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am building a Query for cypher using Neo4jClient base on User search term.
my question is how can i load all the related nodes to first node that i am searching for.

here is a code sample in neo4jclient  :

```
q.Return(post => post.As<Post>()).OrderBy("post.creationDate");
```

which produce something like this in cypher but without the result part:

```
MATCH (post:Post)-[:HAS_MentionedUsers]->(assignee1307989068:User),(post:Post)-[:HAS_HashTags]->    (Hashtag1841024507:HashTag)
WHERE (assignee1307989068.UserName = "mhs")
OR (Hashtag1841024507.Value = "myTag")
```

I am searching for the post but i need all the related node to Post to be included in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have indexes for :User(UserName) and :HashTag(Value)

You create a cross product here, not sure that you want this, probably a union is better

You can just expand the pattern to contain other relationships off :Post too.

```
MATCH (o)-[r]-(post:Post)-[:HAS_MentionedUsers]->(assignee1307989068:User),
WHERE (assignee1307989068.UserName = "mhs")
RETURN post,o,r
UNION
MATCH (o)-[r]-(post:Post)-[:HAS_HashTags]->    (Hashtag1841024507:HashTag)
WHERE (Hashtag1841024507.Value = "myTag")
RETURN post,o,r
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, But as I mentioned How its going to work with neo4jclient (the .Net Library). and also as I have said I am building this query based on search terms that end user is providing. I am not sure how to include the o,r at the end of cypher query while i am not sure if there is any.
I can include the o, and the r in the result set in neo4jclient but what if the post is alone there without any relation. is that going to be a problem?
I can see there is a solution here....!

Comment: The problem is that (o) does not capture assignee1307989068 and Hashtag1841024507 and I have to Include the assignee1307989068  and 
Hashtag1841024507  in thre return part of the query which is nearly impossible in neo4jclient when I am building the query automatically.